# Lookahead captures unwanted characterrs

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to capture alert names that come from the firewall. Each log has the following format:

```
datetime alertname severity_level username endpoint_name domain
```

The current RegEx I'm using works for all logs except for the third one. Any ideas on how to fix it?

```
regex = []

text = """2023-05-27 / 23:06:31 Computer account added/changed/deleted. medium ANONYMOUS LOGON PC-CR5$ SRVDC2 ACME 1
2023-05-27 / 23:28:08 Computer account added/changed/deleted. medium ANONYMOUS LOGON SRVXAP02$ SRVDC2 ACME 1
2023-05-28 / 02:24:29 User account locked out multiple login errors high SRVDC2$ john.smith.admin SRVDC2 \\\\NECBROWSER 1
2023-05-28 / 05:01:48 Computer account added/changed/deleted. medium ANONYMOUS LOGON SRVNPS01$ SRVDC1 ACME 1
2023-05-28 / 06:38:57 Computer account added/changed/deleted. medium ANONYMOUS LOGON VD-OPERATOR1$ SRVDC1 ACME 1"""

pattern = '(?:(?<=\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}))(.*)(?=\.)|(?=medium )|(?=high )|(?=low )|(?=critical )'
regex.append(re.findall(pattern,text,re.MULTILINE))
print(regex)
```

Current Output

```
[[' Computer account added/changed/deleted', '', ' Computer account added/changed/deleted', '', ' User account locked out multiple login errors high SRVDC2$ john.smith', ' Computer account added/changed/deleted', '', ' Computer account added/changed/deleted', '']]
```

Expected Output

```
[[' Computer account added/changed/deleted', '', ' Computer account added/changed/deleted', '', ' User account locked out multiple login errors', ' Computer account added/changed/deleted', '', ' Computer account added/changed/deleted', '']]
```

Comment: Maybe something like `(?:(?<=\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}))\s(.*)\s((?=medium\s)|(?=high\s)|(?=low\s)|(?=critical\s))`

Comment: Good idea with the space, but that returns a completely empty list.

Comment: Lookarounds are not required for this, unless this is part of a larger expression and you need the threat assessment for another part of the overall regex. You should use a capturing group for the part you want to grab instead, which has the added benefit of making your expression shorter and more readable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s+
(.*?)
\s(?:medium|high|low|critical)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/i6DtmP/1).

In contrast to your original attempt, this one uses a non-capturing group (lookbehinds are "expensive"!) and a lazy quantifier construct afterwards. Just use the first capturing group.

In `Python` this could be

```
import re

text = """2023-05-27 / 23:06:31 Computer account added/changed/deleted. medium ANONYMOUS LOGON PC-CR5$ SRVDC2 ACME 1
2023-05-27 / 23:28:08 Computer account added/changed/deleted. medium ANONYMOUS LOGON SRVXAP02$ SRVDC2 ACME 1
2023-05-28 / 02:24:29 User account locked out multiple login errors high SRVDC2$ john.smith.admin SRVDC2 \\\\NECBROWSER 1
2023-05-28 / 05:01:48 Computer account added/changed/deleted. medium ANONYMOUS LOGON SRVNPS01$ SRVDC1 ACME 1
2023-05-28 / 06:38:57 Computer account added/changed/deleted. medium ANONYMOUS LOGON VD-OPERATOR1$ SRVDC1 ACME 1"""

pattern = re.compile(r'''
    \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s+
    (.*?)
    \s(?:medium|high|low|critical)

''', re.VERBOSE)

messages = [match.group(1) for match in pattern.finditer(text)]
print(messages)
```

And would yield

```
['Computer account added/changed/deleted.', 'Computer account added/changed/deleted.', 'User account locked out multiple login errors', 'Computer account added/changed/deleted.', 'Computer account added/changed/deleted.']
```

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/jD2Qbb).

Comment: That worked perfectly. Lookarounds still get me often. Thanks!

Comment: @OverflowStack: Look at the code in the answer below.

Comment: You can remove the lookahead and simplify your expression to something like `\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} (.*) (?:medium|high|low|critical) ` since you're using a capturing group. No need for the lazyness since, presumably, the OP wants to match up to the last `(?:medium|high|low|critical)` on the line anyway.